# Why background processes in shell can print to terminal?

Tags: shell, signals

I know this problem has been asked before in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/972968/why-does-a-background-process-started-in-bash-print-stdout-to-screen), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662817/why-can-i-see-the-output-of-background-processes). But I feel the answers did not fully solve my puzzles.

Let's say I'm implementing my own shell. And by default I'll put every process in background. The code snippet is as follows:

```c
pid_t rc = fork();
if (rc > 0) {
  int status = 
  setpgid(rc, rc);
  tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, getpgrp());
} else if (rc == 0) {
  reset_signal_handlers(); // this reset all signal handlers to default
  setpgrp();
  execv(args[0], args);
}
```

Based on my understanding, the default signal handler in child process for `SIGTTOU` is to suspend it. So when the child process tries to print to terminal, it should be stopped because of the signal. Why it can still print?

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)#Implementation) it says:

> Shells often override the default stop action of SIGTTOU so that background processes deliver their output to the controlling terminal by default.

But I'm implementing my own shell and I did not override any handlers in child process. Why the `SIGTTOU` signal is still ignored?

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior for background process can be configured. The default behavior (from most login shells) is to stop when the background process tries to read from the terminal, and to allow tthe background process to send output.

The `signal on output` behavior can be can be requested

- `stty tostop` (get SIGTTOU from background)
- `stty -tostop` (no SIGTTOU on background processes)

Also possible to modify via ioctl, see 'man ioctl_tty'

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure, this means the default action for *terminal* is *not* sending `SIGTTOU` to background processes right?